how to display progress when building from source in `pip install -e .`
maybe there is a better way to phrase this question.
I am trying to build from source of
vllm: https://github.com/vllm-project/vllm which involves building some cuda and cpp source files.
I suspect somewhere inside the following import might be able to capture the progress like what tqdm can do. However, I don't seem to see a way to achieving something similar to tqdm.
from setuptools import Extension, find_packages, setup
from setuptools.command.build_ext import build_ext

